# angular2 background on table element security

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

I'm trying to display a background image in my `td` element.

I have no errors, but it won't display anything at all:

image:

[image: DOM content]

while it should look something like:

[image: Desired DOM content]

**What have I done wrong here?**

Html:

```
 <td *ngFor="let gamesuits of mynumbers;let i = index; "  class="test"  [style.background.image]="getImage(gamesuits.suit,gamesuits.number)">
            <img src="/assets/placeholder.png" style="cursor:pointer" id="hold_card1">
          </td>
```

more specific:

```
[style.background.image]="getImage(gamesuits.suit,gamesuits.number)"
```

controller:

```
  getImage(suit,number) {
      return   this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle("url('/assets/cards/' + suit + '' + number +'.gif')");


}
```

Comment: Have you considered an `<img>`? You wouldn’t have to bypass anything.

Comment: yeah. But i have to use it as it is atm to make some toggles inside.